# MonoTouch - Upload/Save image (or access Gallery images)

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop, ipad

I'm a musician and I'm writing a small app for my own use on the iPad: I want to store my scanned music sheets (saved as .TIF files) on the iPad, and create set-list, search by artist, song title, do some filtering, etc... with the app.

How can I upload images to my app directory (or saved from a website, I have a website that store those images already)? If it's not possible, I'm thinking about syncing all the images to the iPad image gallery, but how do I access them from my app?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you mean … Download image from the web?

Comment: Yes, either that or to upload from my HDD to my iPad app. I have hundreds of music sheets in .TIF (and PDF) format that I would like to write a small app to manage those. Thank you.

Comment: i'd use the built in mechanism of saving to gallery then access that from in app if i were you

Comment: Do you have any link or tutorial on how to accomplish this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use WebCient to download the image and store it in the Documents directory of your application sandbox.